# Error when applying formatting to float

Tags: python

```
soldpricemean = '{:,}'.format(bedbath_df.sold_price.mean().astype(int))
```

For some reason this way of formatting a float work in one program I wrote, but not the current one I'm working on. The error I get is:

> AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'astype'

can someone please explain why this might be? thanks!

Comment: This has nothing to do with formatting. The expression `bedbath_df.sold_price.mean().astype(int)` fails, because `bedbath_df.sold_price.mean()` is an object of type `float`, which doesn't have a `.astype()` method.

Comment: Drop the `.astype(int)` part and the formatting itself is fine.

Comment: I dropped the .astype(int) but I still get a decimal "452,500.0". How can I trim that off without converting to a string? thanks guys I'm only 2 weeks in.

Comment: That is the correct representation of the float value, I don't know what you think you need to trim off. What is the *expected output* that you wanted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't the formatting. As the error clearly states, the `float` object has no attribute `astype`. I'm assuming you got this from a different language, but in Python that's not how you change types.

If you want to convert a `float` to an `int`, the syntax is `int(float)`, not `float.astype(int)`. You need the code `soldpricemean = '{:,}'.format(int(bedbath_df.sold_price.mean()))`

Comment: I think I'm just getting confused between pandas and python, because pandas documentation has astype() - I just got mixed up where it should be used. Thanks!